# How the charge will be distributed between a charged rod and a neutral sphere, what will be the charge on each after contact?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

When a charged sphere (charge = Q1) and an uncharted sphere of same radius are brought in contact, then the final charge on both spheres will be Q/2. But what will happen if different shapes (one charge and other uncharged) are made in contact with each other. What will be the magnitude of charge on both of them ?

Comment: Recommend adding the word "conducting" somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: It depends on the shape and size of both the conductors. The principle which is followed is that the charge will flow in such a way that the final electrostatic potential of both the conductors becomes equal after we touch them. More about charges and fields [here](https://sarathiacademy.com/sims/charges-and-fields_en.html).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer will be very hard to predict. Consider, for example, the second object is a smaller sphere. It would be ridiculous to assume that an arbitrarily small sphere will always receive half the charge.

The full answer is - charge will flow until the entire surface of both conductors is the same voltage/potential. To find precisely how much charge is on either surface, except in exceptional circumstances, you would need to use a numerical solver to find the distribution of charge that makes both surfaces equipotentials. And in general it will depend on how they touch.

The only reason your original question was so easy to answer was because of symmetry. Of course if both balls are at the same potential, they will have the same total charge.

Comment: Thank you sir for clear explanation, it's a request can you please help me with the following problem : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/759524/364193?sem=2